# How to strict to run a command on a google cloud bucket from an user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

`gsutil rm -r gs://<bucket>/<directory>/` removes both live as well as versioned object from the directory and there is no way to recover the deleted data. Someone who have object delete permission may run the command accidentally. I want to strict the users from running the command. How can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ACLs to control access from buckets onto GCP project; how described from [Gdoc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) "..You most likely want to use ACLs if you need to customize access to individual objects within a bucket.." also from Cloud IAM you can edit/create roles.

From Cloud Console you can add new [entry](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) to grant permission required to a scope.

[image]

If I'm not wrong using the **roles/ storage.legacyBucketReader** as role can be enough.

Then using [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) check out the current members from the bucket `gsutil iam get gs://<bucket_name>`

Also, from the [Gdoc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam) you can see many other examples using gsutil commands to control  permissions

note: We have a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions) to set up ACL entries from a bucket/object:

> "The maximum number of ACL entries you can create for a bucket or
>   object is 100. When the entry scope is a group or domain, it counts as
>   one ACL entry regardless of how many users are in the group or
>   domain."

hope can be useful.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't solve my issue. i don't want to change the access/role to the users. I only want to protect the versioned object from being deleted by the users.